# Javascript - Probleme with .append method

Tags: javascript, xml

I've a probleme with .append method.
I have a XML and I want to add a node in each "locale" nodes.
This is my code :

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")
newElement = xmlDoc.createElement("version_whats_new");
x[0].append(newElement)
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")[0])
x[1].append(newElement)
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")[1])
x[2].append(newElement)
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")[2])
x[3].append(newElement)
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")[3])
```

(I know I can use a loop, but it's just for a better understanding)

After these lines, "version_whats_new" node is present in the node "locale"[3] but not in the others.

Let's imagine my code become :

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")
newElement = xmlDoc.createElement("version_whats_new");
x[0].append(newElement)
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")[0])
x[1].append(newElement)
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("locale")[1])
x[2].append(newElement)
```

"version_whats_new" node gonna be present in the node "locale"[1] but not in the [0]

I've look for a solution during few hours but without any success ... :(

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to clone the `newElement` node three more times?

Comment: Each time you use append you remove the object from the thing it was originally appended to.  So it ends up in the last place you put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element can't exist in multiple places at the same time. So if it is part of a document already, and you append it somewhere else, then it has to be removed from wherever it was before.

You need to call `createElement` multiple times (or make use of `cloneNode`) so you can append **different** elements each time.